# how to query oracle using ExecuteXmlReader and ExecuteStream

Tags: xml, oracle

I want to use ExecuteXmlReader and ExecuteStream methods for oracle using c#.
I've tried various queries but non of them work.
What I need is an xml query in oracle.

For example, for microsoft sql, I converted string to xml as:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @string ='<bookstore><book>Candide</book<>/bookstore>';SET @xml = CAST(@string AS XML);
SELECT @xml;
```

I need something similar to in oracle.
I've tried:

```
select * from XMLType('<bookstore><book>Candide</book<>/bookstore>')
```

which fails.
I know the purpose is unclear. I'm trying to **test** these two methods and my database does not have any data stored in xml format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select xmltype('<bookstore><book>Candide</book></bookstore>') from dual;
```

Check i change your string, because it had token errors.

Comment: thanks. I did not know about dual. The query you posted works fine in oracle dev tool; however, in c# it throws an Exception saying that "the method or operation is not implemented". I know this is an additional question, but plz let me know if you have any ideas.